# Insert into a table with specific value from another table based on condition

Tags: sql

I have a table called Node with 4 columns in which the data are populated for all the fields except Lat and Long

```
  TABLE(
  ID int not null
  Column2 int not null
  Column3 int not null
  Column4 int not null
  LAT float 
  LONG float
)
```

I have another table called "test" with 3 columns with date populated

```
TABLE
( 
 ID,
  LAT
  LONG
)
```

If ID from test matches with Id from node the corresponding lat an long values from test should be inserted into Node.

I tried some thing like this but it give

```
INSERT INTO tblNode(x,y) 
SELECT tpn.Longitude,tpn.Latitude FROM dbo.Node n
    JOIN test tpn
    ON tpn.NodeID = n.NodeID
```

Error
   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table

Can Some one help me with this query.

Comment: PLEASE do not keep changing the table/column names!! You have ID then NodeID, Lat/Long then Latitude/Longitude then X/Y. The table name is **Node** then insert into **tblNode**...

Comment: dang i'm confused what is tpn and what is n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were creating new records, you would include the ID

```
INSERT INTO tblNode(nodeID,x,y) 
SELECT tpn.nodeID, tpn.Longitude,tpn.Latitude FROM dbo.Node n
    JOIN test tpn
    ON tpn.NodeID = n.NodeID
```

However, looking at your question closely you don't want to `INSERT`.  You want to `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE n
SET Lat = tpn.Longitude, Lon = tpn.Latitude
FROM Node n
JOIN test tpn ON tpn.NodeID = n.NodeID
```